# Docker for Mac nginx example doesn't run

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-for-mac

Mac 10.11.5 here. I am specifically trying to install **Docker for Mac** (*not* Docker Toolbox or any other offering). I followed all the instructions on their [Installation page](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/), and everything was going fine until they ask you to try running an nginx server (*Step 3. Explore the application and run examples*).

Running `docker run hello-world` worked beautifully with no problems at all. I was able to see the correct console output that was expected for that image.

**However**, they then ask you to try running an nginx instance:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx
```

I ran this, and got no errors. Console output was expected:

```
Unable to find image 'nginx:latest' locally latest: Pulling from library/nginx
51f5c6a04d83: Pull complete 
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
51d229e136d0: Pull complete 
bcd41daec8cc: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:0fe6413f3e30fcc5920bc8fa769280975b10b1c26721de956e1428b9e2f29d04
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
ae8ee4595f47e7057e527342783d035b224afd17327b057331529e2820fe2b61
```

So then I ran `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                         NAMES
ae8ee4595f47        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   12 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp   webserver
```

So far so good. But then I open up my browser and point it to `http://localhost` and I get (in Chrome):

[image]

Any ideas where I'm going awry? I waited 5 mins just to give nginx/docker ample time to start up, but that doesn't change anything.

---

For tracking purposes, the related GitHub issue:

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/393

Comment: Does the container exit at all, or is still running if you do a `docker ps`? First thing I might try just to check any port issues is to try a different port `-p 8080:80` maybe? The try hitting `localhost:8080`.

Comment: Thanks @Nio (+1) - that worked!

Comment: Use netstat to see what is using your port 80 locally. Mac has Apache installed by default maybe it is running but not configured with a home dir.

Comment: Shouldn't you use docker-machine ip to find out the ip address of your container and then visit http://{IP}/ on your host's browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**corrected**

The image exposes 80 as the httpd port https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/11fc019b2be3ad51ba5d097b1857a099c4056213/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile#L25

So using `-p 80:80` should work and does work for me:

```
docker run -p 80:80 nginx
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2016:17:26:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

So most probably you either run a httpd container on the host so the port cannot be binded  ( should be visible through the start ) or you probably have an issue with `localhost` - does `127.0.0.1` work? You might have a issue with `ipv6` then
Or better using a docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'
services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

and the start it with `docker-compose up` - you can know easily add other services, like a tomcat, puma server, or a FPM upstream, whatever app you might have.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene (and +1) but even if that *were* true, I'd say that this is a bug in Docker for Mac's *documentation*, could anyone disagree?! How should someone brand new to Docker know that they are supposed to follow the installation instructions up to Step 3, but then go to nginx's Docker Hub page and follow those instructions instead?!? **But much more importantly** nothing changes when I try going to `http://localhost:8080`, and running Docker Compose is not (nor should be!) a pre-requisite to running Docker for Mac better or more easily! Any other ideas?

Comment: Thats not true. The port mapping is host:container. Check the Dockerfile for the default image on Jessie - https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile. It is port 80 as standard HTTP web port that is exposed.

Comment: interesting, you are right, i mixed stuff up. Actually the nginx container does exposes 80 https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/11fc019b2be3ad51ba5d097b1857a099c4056213/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile#L25 so this should actually work

Comment: interesting, you are right, i mixed stuff up. Actually the nginx container does exposes 80 https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/11fc019b2be3ad51ba5d097b1857a099c4056213/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile#L25 so this should actually work. using `docker run -p 80:80 nginx` i cant connect to localhost nginx without issues - so i cannot reproduce your issue.  Please ensure you do not run a httpd server on the host already

Answer (score 1):

Try

`` curl -XGET `docker-machine ip`:80 ``

Answer (score 0):

If you're running docker-machine, then run 'docker-machine ls' in your terminal and get the ip of your virtual host. Instead of typing in localhost, paste the virtual host's ip into your internet browser and it should work.

Comment: I confirm that this does work.  Curious though why localhost doesn't work for some people.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when run on Chrome, but it is work on Safari.

After a while pull my hair, i found out that my machine connected to a proxy, and this is problem.
I must stop server, remove image, turn off proxy and pull it again.